# implementing html5 banner ad

Tags: css, html, banner-ads

Good Afternoon, I created a banner ad in HTML5 using div containers and css3 animation. I submitted my banner to who i needed to submit it to and they responded they want a gif file. I'm a little confused as to what they need. how do i convert the html5 to a gif. It seems they're following XAXIS/Google ADX criteria. I know that they do not actually want an animated gif, but are looking for a backup of sorts. Never dealt with this type of stuff so your help is greatly appreciated. Here's the documentation:

Initial Load - 200kb
Secondary Load
Max Additional Load - 1 MB
Max number of file requests – 15
Backup static image must be supplied separate from the HTML5 zip for trafficking
DCM doesn’t accept HTML files which are made using the SWIFFY tool
HMTL must include at least 1 clickTAG (See Below for the clickTag supported by DCM)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name=”ad.size” content=”width=300,height=250”>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var clickTag = 'https://www.google.com'; 
</script>
</head>
<body>
[The rest of your creative code goes here.] 
</html>

Please ensure that your creative uses the clicktag variable as the click-through URL:
<a href='javascript:window.open(window.clickTag)'>
<img src='images/dclk.png' border=0>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Display your HTML-based banner in a web browser, take a screen capture, and edit it down to the right size with an image editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All banners require a static backup gif (or jpg, or png) that displays when the animated version fails to load. If you don't have a Photoshop layout to make a static version from you can do this:

- Run the banner locally in your browser
- Take a screenshot of the frame you want for the static version
- Crop the image down to banner size & save as gif, jpg, png or whatever